# Export photos from Galaxy Nexus (w/ Jelly Bean) to Win 7

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, photos, 4.1-jelly-bean

I upload photos from my Galaxy Nexus (w/ Jelly Bean) directly to Google+, but I would also like to periodically export photos from my phone to my Win 7 desktop.

I tried Picasa 3.9, but it would always freeze and I would have to force quit Picasa.

I tried Windows 7's photo software (Windows Live Photo Gallery), but it would export every photo, including cached websites.

Is there a simple solution? Or will I need to manually move photos from my Galaxy Nexus to my Win 7 desktop? FWIW, the only feature set I really want is exporting photos/videos to folders based on date taken. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it on Windows 7, but I expect Dropbox will work fine.

Comment: Good point... Do you mean by running the Dropbox client on my phone? Or still connecting to the desktop with USB?

Comment: Dropbox client on the phone and PC.  Phone will upload the photos, and PC will automatically sync them down.

Comment: Dropbox works great on Windows 7; I use it myself. If you don't want to leave your photos in the "Camera Uploads" folder, you can use something like [Belvedere](http://lifehacker.com/341950/belvedere-automates-your-self+cleaning-pc) to automatically move them to, say, your "My Pictures" folder.

Comment: This works. I hoped that the Dropbox client worked better than the Win 7 import, but it doesn't (it doesn't import anything). I have to run the client on my phone _and_ my desktop and move photos from my phone to my desktop via Dropbox, which is kind of a Rube Goldberg. I guess I will get used to managing my photos G+. :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you not share a folder on your Windows machine and then use ES File Explorer or similar to copy the files across from the phone? Obviously whilst on the same local network.

It would cut out having to transfer them to a remote location and back again.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think this is better than a USB connection and manually moving? I think I will get used to managing my photos on G+.

Comment: I guess the advantage is only that you don't have to physically connect the Nexus 7 to your PC :)